# MS GraphAPI PHP SDK fails creating a new folder

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to create a folder in my Sharepoint site using the PHP SDK, starting from this sample in the MS Learn site.

[Create a new folder in a drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=php)

Here's my code

```
public function createFolder($folderName)
{
    try {
        $requestBody = new DriveItem();
        $requestBody->setName($folderName);
        $folder = new Folder();
        $requestBody->setFolder($folder);
        $additionalData = [
            '@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior' => 'rename',
        ];      
        $requestBody->setAdditionalData($additionalData);

        $response = $this->graphServiceClient->drives()->byDriveId($this->driveId)->items()->byDriveItemId("root")->children()->post($requestBody)->wait();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Invoking the post() method generate an exception with a 400 response code and this error message

`[item] Read called with an open stream or textreader. Please close any open streams or text readers before calling Read.`

The stack trace

```
#0 \vendor\microsoft\kiota-serialization-json\src\JsonParseNode.php(108): Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Models\ODataErrors\ODataError::createFromDiscriminatorValue(Object(Microsoft\Kiota\Serialization\Json\JsonParseNode))
#1 \vendor\microsoft\kiota-http-guzzle\src\GuzzleRequestAdapter.php(637): Microsoft\Kiota\Serialization\Json\JsonParseNode->getObjectValue(Array)
#2 \vendor\microsoft\kiota-http-guzzle\src\GuzzleRequestAdapter.php(156): Microsoft\Kiota\Http\GuzzleRequestAdapter->throwFailedResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array, Object(OpenTelemetry\API\Trace\NonRecordingSpan))
#3 \vendor\php-http\promise\src\FulfilledPromise.php(39): Microsoft\Kiota\Http\GuzzleRequestAdapter->Microsoft\Kiota\Http\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#4 \vendor\microsoft\kiota-http-guzzle\src\GuzzleRequestAdapter.php(164): Http\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure))
#5 \vendor\microsoft\microsoft-graph\src\Generated\Drives\Item\Items\Item\Children\ChildrenRequestBuilder.php(84): Microsoft\Kiota\Http\GuzzleRequestAdapter->sendAsync(Object(Microsoft\Kiota\Abstractions\RequestInformation), Array, Array)
#6 \common\class\GraphAssihub.php(172): Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Drives\Item\Items\Item\Children\ChildrenRequestBuilder->post(Object(Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Models\DriveItem))
#7 \cp\ajax\pagetest.php(169): GraphAssihub->createFolder('new_folder')
#8 {main}
```

Calling

`POST /drives/{drive-id}/items/root/children`

via graph-explorer works properly, so I think permissions are ok.

Calling

`$this->graphServiceClient->drives()->byDriveId($this->driveId)->items()->byDriveItemId("root")->children()->get()->wait()`

via PHP works properly and returns all the items in the root directory.

One of this items is a folder, so I tried to create the new folder inside this existing folder, getting the same exception.

What I'm doing wrong?

#### Updated Wed Dec 06 09:23:00 2023 UTC

Starting from ChildrenRequestBuilder and following the internal calls

```
ChildrenRequestBuilder.post()
-> GuzzleRequestAdapter.sendAsync()
-> GuzzleRequestAdapter.getHttpResponseMessage()
  $request = $this->authenticationProvider->authenticateRequest($requestInfo, $additionalAuthContext);
  $request->then(
    ...
    $psrRequest = $this->getPsrRequestFromRequestInformation($requestInfo, $httpResponseSpan);
    ...
  )->then(function (ResponseInterface $response)
    ...
  )
```

this is the $psrRequest

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request {#212 
  -method: "POST"
  -requestTarget: null
  -uri: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri {#224 
    -scheme: "https"
    -userInfo: ""
    -host: "graph.microsoft.com"
    -port: null
    -path: "/v1.0/drives/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/items/root/children"
    -query: ""
    -fragment: ""
    -composedComponents: null
  }
  -headers: array:4 [
    "Host" => array:1 [
      0 => "graph.microsoft.com"
    ]
    "accept" => array:1 [
      0 => "application/json;q=1"
    ]
    "content-type" => array:1 [
      0 => "application/json"
    ]
    "authorization" => array:1 [
      0 => "Bearer xxxxxxxx"
    ]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:4 [
    "accept" => "accept"
    "content-type" => "content-type"
    "authorization" => "authorization"
    "host" => "Host"
  ]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream {#73 
    -stream: stream resource @643 
      wrapper_type: "PHP"
      stream_type: "TEMP"
      mode: "w+b"
      unread_bytes: 0
      seekable: true
      uri: "php://temp"
      options: []
    }
    -size: 135
    -seekable: true
    -readable: true
    -writable: true
    -uri: "php://temp"
    -customMetadata: []
  }
}
```

and this is the $response

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response {#262 
  -reasonPhrase: "Bad Request"
  -statusCode: 400
  -headers: array:8 [
    "Cache-Control" => array:1 [
      0 => "no-store, no-cache"
    ]
    "Transfer-Encoding" => array:1 [
      0 => "chunked"
    ]
    "Content-Type" => array:1 [
      0 => "application/json"
    ]
    "Strict-Transport-Security" => array:1 [
      0 => "max-age=31536000"
    ]
    "request-id" => array:1 [
      0 => "xxxxxxx"
    ]
    "client-request-id" => array:1 [
      0 => "xxxxxxx"
    ]
    "x-ms-ags-diagnostic" => array:1 [
      0 => "{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Switzerland North","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"xxxxx"}}"
    ]
    "Date" => array:1 [
      0 => "Wed, 06 Dec 2023 08:43:38 GMT"
    ]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:8 [
    "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
    "transfer-encoding" => "Transfer-Encoding"
    "content-type" => "Content-Type"
    "strict-transport-security" => "Strict-Transport-Security"
    "request-id" => "request-id"
    "client-request-id" => "client-request-id"
    "x-ms-ags-diagnostic" => "x-ms-ags-diagnostic"
    "date" => "Date"
  ]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream {#207 
    -stream: stream resource @646 
      wrapper_type: "PHP"
      stream_type: "TEMP"
      mode: "w+b"
      unread_bytes: 0
      seekable: true
      uri: "php://temp"
      options: []
    }
    -size: null
    -seekable: true
    -readable: true
    -writable: true
    -uri: "php://temp"
    -customMetadata: []
  }
}
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Odds are that you get an exception with a full backtrace, which is mostly swallowed. That's important info though. Also, you could step through the code in a debugger. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: UPDATED: added stacktrace

Comment: Check the generated HTTP request at the endpoint in `ChildrenRequestBuilder` and paste the request (headers, body) that's being generated, please.

Comment: UPDATED first post: search "Updated Wed Dec 06 09:23:00 2023 UTC"